# Can I create multi-line tick labels in Dojo Charts?

Tags: dojo, dojox.charting

I have a 2D dojox.chart. I want to label tick marks on the X axis with dates that have time and date on separate lines. Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is quite a simple way. Just add a `<br/>` tag between your date and time in your `labelFunc` or in the text for values that you generate:

```
labelFunc: function(value){
    return value +"<br/>"+"sometext";
}
```

Comment: What version of dojo charting are you using?  When I use the above I see `<br/>` rendered as text in the label.  It is not HTML.